# Latest Imap server Library

Tags: c#, imap

Does anyone knows good and latest imap server library in C#? Already I used lumisoft imap library. But, as the gmail has changed it's settings, I cannot use it anymore. Need latest imap server library...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the latest imap server coding in the following link.. Some of the functions has been changed.. It is working.. Thank you everyone

http://www.lumisoft.ee/lsWWW/Download/Downloads/Net/

Answer (score -2):

Try [Mail.dll email component](http://www.lesnikowski.com/mail/), it's very easy to use.

It supports **SSL**, MIME (downloads attachments), S/MIME (secure signatures), includes IMAP, POP3 and SMTP clients:

```
using(Imap imap = new Imap())
{
    imap.ConnectSSL("imapServer");
    imap.Login("user", "password");

    imap.SelectInbox();
    List<long> uids = imap.SearchFlag(Flag.Unseen);

    foreach (long uid in uids)
    {
        string eml = imap.GetMessageByUID(uid);
        IMail email = new MailBuilder()
            .CreateFromEml(eml);

        Console.WriteLine(email.Subject);
        Console.WriteLine(email.TextDataString);
    }
    imap.Close(true);
}
```

Please note that this is a commercial product that I've created.

Comment: Super easy to use compared to others I was struggling with; a free download lets you try it to see if it's easy or not. @Pawel, I will be recommending my client buys the library.

Comment: I think if you can't see the difference between server and client library then your library obviously sucks.

Comment: @aloneguid You are right, my bad. Still Mail.dll is very good _client_ library.

Answer (score -2):

You may want to try our [Rebex Mail](http://www.rebex.net/secure-mail.net/). It includes SMTP/SSL, IMAP/SSL, SMTP/SSL, S/MIME.

Following code shows how to download the message list from Gmail IMAP server:

```
// connect and log in
Imap imap = new Imap();
imap.Connect("imap.gmail.com", 993, null, ImapSecurity.Implicit);
imap.Login(username, password);

// process messagess...
ImapMessageCollection messages =
    client.GetMessageList(ImapListFields.Envelope);

// display info about each message 
Console.WriteLine("UID | From | To | Subject");
foreach (ImapMessageInfo message in messages)
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        "{0} | {1} | {2} | {3}",
        message.UniqueId,
        message.From,
        message.To,
        message.Subject);
}

// logout and disconnect
imap.Disconnect();
```

You can download it from [rebex.net/secure-mail.net/download.aspx](http://www.rebex.net/secure-mail.net/download.aspx)